# How do I drag and drop a movie file (.mov) in my MacOS app?

Tags: macos, drag-and-drop, quicktime

I know how to drag and drop image files in my MacOS app (using the methods draggingEntered:, prepareForDragOperation: and performDragOperation:). But I can't figure out how to do the same for movie files. Is that possible and if so how to proceed? (It would be helpful if there is some sample code to look at).

Answer (score 1):

It bascially should be the same, except the accepted files becomes movie files.

Example code for you:

DragContainer.swift file

```
import Cocoa

protocol DragContainerDelegate {
    func draggingEntered()
    func draggingExit()
    func draggingFileAccept(_ file: URL)
}

class DragContainer: NSView {
    var delegate: DragContainerDelegate?

    let acceptTypes = ["mov", "mp4", "avi", "m4v"]


    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String),
                                 NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeItem as String)])
    }


    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        delegate?.draggingEntered()
        let acceptFiles = checkExtension(sender)
        return acceptFiles ? NSDragOperation.generic : NSDragOperation()
    }

    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        delegate?.draggingExit()
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue:"NSFilenamesPboardType")) as? [String],
            let path = board.first{
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            delegate?.draggingFileAccept(url)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func checkExtension(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = draggingInfo.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(rawValue:"NSFilenamesPboardType")) as? [String],
            let path = board.first{
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let fileExtension = url.pathExtension.lowercased()
            if acceptTypes.contains(fileExtension) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

ViewController.swift file

```
class ViewController: NSViewController,DragContainerDelegate {
    func draggingEntered() {

    }

    func draggingExit() {

    }

    func draggingFileAccept(_ file: URL) {
        print(file)
        // do whatever you want here 
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var dragContainer: DragContainer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dragContainer.delegate = self
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```